# How to ensure that name of category is displayed rather than id in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey Guys need your help with the windows forms application that I try to develop, that is, I have a combobox which is bound to category table and properly displays name of the category but when new record is submitted, then only Id of category is shown in datagridview but I want to ensure that the name of category is displayed rather than the Id. Look in the picture below I need to change int(id of category) to string(name of category) [The Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oD5B.png) Down below is code that I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ТестовоеЗадание.DAL;

namespace ТестовоеЗадание
{
    public partial class РасходыForm : Form
    {

        private DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
        Расходы model = new Расходы();

        public РасходыForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Расходы_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateComboboxWithDataGrid();

        }
       void PopulateComboboxWithDataGrid()
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Расходы.ToList();
            cbxCategory.DataSource = db.КатегорииЗатрат.ToList();
            cbxCategory.ValueMember = "Id";
            cbxCategory.DisplayMember = "Наименование";


        }


        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (MessageBox.Show("Уверены что хотите удалить эту категорию?", "Удаление", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)

            {
                {
                    var entry = db.Entry(model);
                    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)

                        db.Расходы.Attach(model);
                    db.Расходы.Remove(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    MessageBox.Show("Запись была удалена");

                }
            }
                }

        private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.Период = dtp.Value;
            model.Стоимость = decimal.Parse(tbxCost.Text);
            model.КатегорииЗатратId =(int)(cbxCategory.SelectedValue);
            model.Комментарий = tbxComments.Text;
            db.Расходы.Add(model);
           db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Запись успешно сохранена");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to  shown category name in datagridview or combobox? please write in details

Comment: @ershoaib Hi! thank you for your attention, I need to show category name in datagridview

Comment: does your `db.Расходы.ToList();` gives you all columns in table please check? bcoz datagridview shows all column that provided in `dataGridView1.DataSource`

Comment: @ershoaib Yes, it shows all data from database please check out the picture I have attached above. Just click "The Picture" link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As According to your problem,you will have to use the entity relation as foreign key of categoryId and use inner join or join query to access the data from both tables.so that you will be able to view category name from category table in Datagridview as such I used store procedure with  inner join to sort out your problem as shown below.Check working and tested result are showing you.

DataBase Tables are mine design according to consideration of your problem as
[image]
[image]

**Entity RelationShip Diagram** 
use primary foreign RelationShip as such ID to Cost table categoryID
[image]
**Stored Procedure** with **inner join** to access data between two tables.

[image]
Call **Stored Procedure** (with Entity Data Model) to get data in datagridview as follow.

[image]

**Output Result** showing category Name as catName
[image]

Comment: @mir 433 kindly accept answer

Comment: Thank you for your attention and reply but is there a solution with just saying datagridview to show string value instead of int value

Comment: lookup to the stored Procedure with inner join and display catName as string instead of int catID.OR made another stored procedure for getting string by passing int value as parameter.